# Tracking down an Umbraco Error Message

Tags: sql, iis-7.5, umbraco

I have a couple of packages installed in my Umbraco installation so it would be kinda hard to to track down each one of them one by one. I get this error message every 5 minutes in the log file:

```
Error executing scheduled task: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString) at umbraco.presentation.publishingService.getTaskByHttp(String url) at umbraco.presentation.publishingService.CheckPublishing(Object sender)
```

Is there a faster way of tracking down the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the built-in task scheduler. Have a look in the config\umbracoSettings.config file and find the scheduledTasks node. There you'll find something that is supposed to run every five minutes and has a wrong URL specified.

Comment: in my case a package had been uninstalled but the scheduled task was still there